# Visual C++ application won't run on windows 7

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, windows-7, windows-10

I am using Visual Studio Community 2015 and I wrote some simple Win32 demo application which should download file from internet and execute two HTTP GET requests.

I am using functions like `InternetOpenA`, `InternetConnectA`, `HttpOpenRequestA`, `URLDownloadToFile`, etc.

Only thing that I have changed in settings is **Platform Toolset** to **Visual Studio 2013 (v120)** and my `targetver.h` file looks like this:

```
#pragma once

// Including SDKDDKVer.h defines the highest available Windows platform.
// If you wish to build your application for a previous Windows platform, include WinSDKVer.h and
// set the _WIN32_WINNT macro to the platform you wish to support before including SDKDDKVer.h.

#include <WinSDKVer.h>

#define WINVER 0x0600
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600 

#include <SDKDDKVer.h>
```

However, it runs on my Windows 10 computer, but it does not run on windows 7. It says: Missing MSVCR120.dll file. I can install appropriate C++ Redistributables but that is not solution that I need.

Is there any other options I need to include when I compile so I can avoid this error?

Comment: it says that you must set the define **before** including `WindSDKVer.h`

Comment: its says before `SDKDDKVer.h`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid your application needing a separate runtime DLL, in the project settings, look under:

C/C++ > Code Generation > Runtime Library

and choose multi-threaded, rather than multi-threaded DLL.

You do not need to change the platform toolset.

Answer (score 0):

In my project, that I compile with VS 2017 and want to run all the way down to Vista, I do the same as you, but without the first `#include <WinSDKVer.h>`. I just set the `_WIN32_WINNT` macro to `0x0600` and so far it's working fine.

I target the Windows 8.1 SDK, and use MFC, if that helps.

I've used [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) in the past to diagnose dll dependencies. Hopefully it's something silly like the 32-bit or 64-bit runtimes being missing.

As keith recommended in his answer, you can also try static linking the vc runtime ([/MT[d]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx) under C++/Code generation/Runtime Library) so that it doesn't need to load the runtime as a dll. Note that this is not the recommended option, since the VC runtime cannot be patched by Windows Update if it's burned into your executible.